# How do I make a Flask app available for my friends through port-forwarding?

Tags: python, flask, port, forwarding

So I created a simple Flask app to automate certain calculations we often have to do in math class. I'm now trying to let my friends use it too but I can't get the local port forwarding right. When I run the app I can access it from my local network but not from outside of it. (I tested that by trying to reach the web app through my phone on mobile data, and it doesn't respond.) I'm aware that ssh tunnelling is probably a better way to do this, but I still want to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

I am very new to this and used this video as a reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfSLxs40sIw. Here's a brief summary of the things I already tried:

I changed `app.run()` to `app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)` to make Flask respond to all public ip's. 
When I now run my app I can access it from my computer via:

http://0.0.0.0:5000/

http://127.0.0.1:5000/

http://192.168.1.101:5000/

I then used freedns.afraid.org to create a subdomain flaskdries.mooo.com. When redirecting the subdomain to the latest ip-adress in the list (192.168.1.101:5000) it would always refuse to connect, even on the pc that's running the app. Using 127.0.0.1:5000 eventually did the trick for all the devices on my network [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZKLM.png), but still not for devices outside of my network.
I guess that's an obvious thing since my WAN ip is nowhere to be specified in this method. So if I'm correct, when someone goes to the subdomain, there is no link to my router so also not to the device running the app. The problem is that I have no clue where I should specify my WAN ip or something similar.

I noticed that when I created the subdomain the destination was automatically set to my WAN ip
[(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J01qO.png). At first I thought simply adding :5000 would work, but unfortunately it doesn't.

As you might have noticed I am extremely new to this and don't really have any other information i can rely on apart from the internet, so any help is welcome!

Thanks in advance,

Dries

Comment: Take a look at https://ngrok.com/

Comment: 192.168.1.101 is a local IP address in your home network. You need to use the external IP that your ISP provided to you. But as mentioned before, ngrok might be an easier solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research I figured out that the problem was that I have a seperate modem and router. For most people one port forward inside the router is enough, but I also had to forward a port from my modem to my router. Kind of annoying that I didn't think of that earlier. Thanks to everybody for responding tho.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to stack overflow.

In order to access you app from the internet you will need an external static IP that you should be able to obtain from your internet provider. You then set your domain to point to that IP. If you don't want to specify the port each time, you can run you flask app on port 80 or 443 if you want https.

Also it is probably advisable to run it behind a web server of some sorts, like nginx since `app.run` is only intended to be used for local development.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the ip adresses of you local network.
If you have port forwarding enabled to you machine then you have to use you public ip adress.
Your router should have the public ip adress in the admin interface.

Simplifiyed explanation:
You domain shoud lead to the external IP of your router. 
Your router then forwards the request to your machine via portforwading (network IP address).

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I can't figure out how I can define to which port on my router the domain leads. As the second picture on my original post indicated I can indeed have a subdomain lead to my external IP of my router, and I can forward port 80 from my router to my personal computer, but when I surf to the domain my router still doesn't know which port it should forward, because it's nowhere specified. In the above method I forwarded to 127.0.0.1:5000 and there is port 5000 specified, but changing that to simply my external ip adress without any port specification doesn't work.

Comment: you have to specify the port in your router interface. if it lets you forward ports then you also should be able to define which ports are exposed to the public and which ports are used on the host machine.

Comment: It allows me to define the port in the router settings but not when setting up the subdomain on freedns.afraid.org: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/J01qO.png
Simply adding my WAN ip there doesn't work.
Here are my port forwarding settings:
https://imgur.com/a/KI41nT8

Comment: I think that there shold be another input field: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/kWpxre1)

Comment: Could you show the rest of the screenshot? Perhaps it's a function that is only avaible on certain types of tp-link routers. Usually it also says on the right side of the screen what each input field means, so I can compare those to mine.

Comment: Its out of a video. [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8lS7YqErtA) .

Comment: I believe the extra input field wouldn't fix the problem. As I said, the problem is that I don't know how how I should specify which port I'm trying to send a request to when entering my routers ip adress in for example an adress bar or in this case the destination of my subdomain. Adding :5000 behind the ip does the trick with an internal ip but not with an external.